# Formatting python docstrings for dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, docstring

What's the recommended way of adding a docstring for a dictionary parameter? I can see multiple line docstring examples [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings).

I need to document the input arguments to a function in the docstring. If it's a simple variable, I can use something like:

```
 def func2(a=x, b = y):
 """ fun2 takes two integers 

 Keyword arguments:
 a -- refers to age (default 18)
 b -- refers to experience (default 0)
 """
```

If we have `dict` passed as input argument to function:

```
 def func3(**kwargs):
     """ takes dictionary as input

      <Here how to explain them - Is it like?> 
      kwargs['key1'] -- takes value1

      <or simply>
      key1 -- takes value1
      """
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you mean? Do you mean how to document a parameter that should be a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, how to document a parameter which is a dictionary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I generally use the [Google docstring style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html), so a dictionary parameter would look like:

```
def func(a_dict):
    """Some function to do something to a dictionary.

    Args:
      a_dict (dict of str: int): Some mapping, I guess?

    """
    ...
```

A function that takes `**kwargs` (note: this is **not** quite the same as having a dictionary parameter), would look like:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    """Some function to do stuff to arbitrary keyword arguments.

    Args:
        **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.

    Keyword Args:
        <kwarg_name> int: A description
        <kwarg_name_2> str: Another description
        <...>

    """
    ...
```

If there are specific parameters that should be present (e.g. your `key1`), they should be separate, not rolled into `**kwargs`.

---

In Python 3.x, you can also use [function annotations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/):

```
def func(a_dict: dict):
    """Some function to do something to a dictionary."""
    ...
```

---

From Python 3.5, you can be even more explicit using [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
from typing import Mapping

def func(a_dict: Mapping[str, int]):
    """Some function to do something to a dictionary."""
    ...
```

Comment: What if you wanted to explicitly type out the dictionary's keys and values? The dictionary has `class_ids` which has a type, `masks` which has a type... etc.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not aware of any convention for that; if that's what you want you'd be better with something like a `namedtuple` with those as *attributes*.

Comment: The docstring you propose Namgyal, `dict of str: int`, is fine. But I don't see any description of it at your link to https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html

Answer (score 4):

For those using PyCharm: You can configure your default docstring formats in:

```
Preferences -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Docstrings
```

as of version `2019` the allowed options are: **Plain, Epytext, reStructuredText, NumPy, Google**. This functionality will automatically add a docstring skeleton once you've typed three double quotes `"` and hit `enter`.